# Spring4: @Component Polymorphism

Tags: spring, polymorphism, components

Spring 4.0
@Component and Polymorphism:

I have the following structure

```
Interface IF {
}

@Component(value="a")
    public class AAA implements IF {
} 

@Component(value="b")
    public class BBB implements IF {
} 


@Component public class Factory {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("a")
    private IF if1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("b")
    private IF if2;
}
```

It does not work for me unlike Spring XML. I guess if I have only one attribute, it works well. I can surely do...

```
@Autowired
private AAA a;

@Autowired
private BBB b;
```

... but I don't want to do that!

Comment: What you are suggesting should work... What the stacktrace you are getting?

Comment: Oh yes, it works. For a change I posted an answer not a question  :)